# Sum values in a list one by one, check for any step if the sum is equal to 0 and store values contributing to the sum to a new list Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
    my_list = [-1, 5, 6, -7, -3, 7, 9, -8, 4, -12, ....., N]
```

Using Python 3.x, I would like to sum numbs one by one and check at each step if the sum is equal to zero. If it is not continue, otherwise break and store values contributing to the sum (when sum = 0) in a new list.

For now, I'm not considering problems regarding performance.
Can you please help me?
Really appreciate your help!

Comment: "I would like to ___" isn't a question. What do you actually want to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to sum up your items until the sum is different from `0` and also save this numbers in another list.

You can do it like this

```
my_list = [-1, 5, 6, -7, -3, 7, 9, -8, 4, -12]
numbers_that_sum_zero = []
total = 0
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    total += my_list[i]
    numbers_that_sum_zero.append(my_list[i])
    if total == 0:
       break
print(numbers_that_sum_zero)
```

This will return

```
[-1, 5, 6, -7, -3]
```

Comment: Good approach! Although I would add a final check to see if total is equal to the desired output sum, otherwise it will return the whole list for the cases where the values don't get the target-sum at all. For example `my_list = [10,20,30,40,50]` certainly doesn't sum to 0, yet it returns the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

An option using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

my_list = [-1, 5, 6, -7, -3, 7, 9, -8, 4, -12]

a = np.array(my_list)
result = a[:a.cumsum().tolist().index(0)+1]
# or result = a[:np.where(a.cumsum()==0)[0][0]+1]
```

Output:

```
array([-1,  5,  6, -7, -3])
```

This returns the first subset of number in which the sum is 0. If there's no values in the list that sums to 0 at all, it raises an error.

You can handle it to return `NaN` or any other output with:

```py
try:
    result = a[:a.cumsum().tolist().index(0)+1]
except:
    result = np.nan
```